# Display loading icon at the beginning in OpenGL ES app for Android

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es

What's the best (and easy) way to display any loading icon (rotating wheel, screen with the word "loading"... anything) at the start of an OpenGL app in Android?
My initialization functions (`onSurfaceCreated` and `onSurfaceChanged`) are quite slow, and I don't want to have a black screen while they load. I tried to draw something with OpenGL in the meantime, but it's impossible in those functions before everything is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't do lengthy operations in either `onSurfaceCreated` and `onSurfaceChanged`. Move costly operations into either a own thread (if not related to OpenGL), or do them on demand in the display functions preparation stage.

Comment: Although this is a valid answer (but sill, doesn't quite address the question), what if those operations *are* related to OpenGL, like loading textures? Those need to be done inside an OpenGL context in order to be able to call the API methods...

Comment: @DarkCygnus: The most lengthy part about loading a texture is loading the actual data from storage, due to limited I/O bandwidth. Offload such I/O operations to a different thread. Use some form of queue to send the loaded data over to the thread that does OpenGL ES, where a worker loop dequeues the work units from the thread and yields after a couple 10 of ms. That would be one way to go about this.

Comment: So, you suggest that the bitmaps are loaded, verified, etc. Before the OGL context, and then, inside the context "just" proceed with obtaining such preprocessed bmps, do the binding, mipmaps, mag/min filters etc.?